# Cron job working, but crontab -l says no jobs

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running Raspbian on a Pi and installed cron to schedule a job. I wrote a Python script and I set it to run every 5 minutes. The job is happening every 5 minutes, no problems, but when I run `crontab -l` as `root` and `pi`, it says there are no jobs. When I run `crontab -e` as `root` and as `pi` they are blank.

I honestly can't remember the exact details of when I set up the job. I know I wrote a line on a document that was formatted like a `crontab` and I am pretty sure it was done as `root`.

I have discovered this as I was going to add some more jobs, and would like to locate the other one I made before I get going on adding more.

Comment: Have you searched cron's spool area?

Comment: There is something in ../spool/cron/ called crontabs, but I don't know what to do with it. Can't read it any way that I have tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two lists of scheduled tasks (crontabs).

Each user (including root) has a per-user crontab which they can list with `crontab -l` and edit with `crontab -e`. The usual Linux implementation of cron stores these files in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. You shouldn't modify these files directly (run `crontab -e` as the user instead), but it's safe to list them to see what's inside. You need to be root to list them.

There is a system crontab as well. This one is maintained by root, and the jobs can run as any user. The system crontab consists of `/etc/crontab` and, on many systems, files in `/etc/cron.d`. These files have an additional column: after the 5 date/time fields, they have a “user” field, which is the user that the job will run as. It's common to set up `/etc/crontab` to run scripts from directories `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, etc. and that's how it's done on Raspbian.

So look in all these places: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/*` (you need to be root for this one), `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.*`.

You can also get information in the system logs. They won't tell you where the job was listed, but they tell you exactly what command is being executed, so you can search for the command text. For example, this is the entry that runs commands in `/etc/cron.hourly` every hour:

```
May 11 07:17:01 darkstar CRON[2480]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: yep. it was in the system crontab.

Answer (score 0):

May be the jobs were given by other users 
Try listing as

```
ls -lR /etc/cron*
```

Comment: Thank you, good idea. Thought I might find them, though maybe this was done as user cron, but nope. All that found was root jobs that I did not create, things like apache2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Global cron entries are often listed in `/etc/crontab`. For specifics about crontabs and their file locations try `man cron` and `man crontab`.

Answer (score -2):

```
crontab -l lists the cron jobs for the default user.
```

Its different from the list that appears from

```
sudo crontab -l
```

It lists the crons created by the root user. Sometimes we get confused when we see the logs showing successful cron jobs while the crontabs does'nt list the expected ones. The current user is the key

Comment: "_when I run crontab -l as root and pi, it says there are no jobs_". They had already tried this